# Extracting GIF frames with gstreamer

Tags: rust, gstreamer, gif

I'm trying to extract the frames of any video (including GIFs) using gstreamer with AppSrc and AppSink. My minimal faulty pipeline in Rust (using the gstreamer crate) is:

```
let buf = /* All in memory for the moment */;

let app_src = ElementFactory::make("appsrc", None).unwrap();
let decodebin = ElementFactory::make("decodebin", None).unwrap();
let app_sink = ElementFactory::make("appsink", None).unwrap();
let pipeline = Pipeline::new();

pipeline.add_many(&[&app_src, &decodebin, &app_sink]).unwrap();
app_src.link(&decodebin).unwrap();

let buf = GstRc::from_slice(buf).unwrap();
let app_src = app_src.downcast::<AppSrc>().unwrap();
app_src.push_buffer(buf).into_result().unwrap();
app_src.end_of_stream().into_result().unwrap();

let app_sink = app_sink.downcast::<AppSink>().unwrap();
app_sink.set_caps(Some(&Caps::from_str(&"video/x-raw")).unwrap()));
app_sink.set_sync(false);
app_sink.set_wait_on_eos(true);

let app_sink2 = app_sink.clone();
decodebin.connect_pad_added(move |decodebin, _| {
    let _ = decodebin.link(&app_sink2);
});

pipeline.set_state(State::Playing).into_result().unwrap();
pipeline
    .get_state(CLOCK_TIME_NONE)
    .0
    .into_result()
    .unwrap()

 /* Pull each frame through with app_sink.pull_sample() */
```

This is working with various videos and even images I've tested, but for any GIF it just errors out on `pipeline.get_state()`. `GST_DEBUG=4` shows:

```
0:00:18.929304768 27027 0x7f48746d8050 INFO                   libav gstavdemux.c:1314:gst_ffmpegdemux_open:<avdemux_gif0:video_0> stream tags: taglist, video-codec=(string)"GIF\ \(Graphics\ Interchange\ Format\)";
0:00:18.929353999 27027 0x7f48746d8050 WARN                   libav gstavdemux.c:1603:gst_ffmpegdemux_loop:<avdemux_gif0> av_read_frame returned -5
0:00:18.929370474 27027 0x7f48746d8050 WARN                   libav gstavdemux.c:1590:gst_ffmpegdemux_loop:<avdemux_gif0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:18.929383308 27027 0x7f48746d8050 WARN                   libav gstavdemux.c:1590:gst_ffmpegdemux_loop:<avdemux_gif0> error: streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
0:00:18.929371274 27027 0x7f48746d8680 INFO            videodecoder gstvideodecoder.c:1330:gst_video_decoder_sink_event_default:<avdec_gif0> upstream tags: taglist, video-codec=(string)"GIF\ \(Graphics\ Interchange\ Format\)";
0:00:18.929406505 27027 0x7f48746d8050 INFO        GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:2145:gst_element_message_full_with_details:<avdemux_gif0> posting message: Internal data stream error.
0:00:18.929462537 27027 0x7f48746d8050 INFO        GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:2172:gst_element_message_full_with_details:<avdemux_gif0> posted error message: Internal data stream error.
```

The error is `av_read_frame returned -5`. `GST_DEBUG=5` doesn't print anything more detailed about the error. Strangely enough, `gst-launch` works:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.gif ! decodebin ! video/x-raw ! fakesink
```

Running that with `GST_DEBUG=4` doesn't show anything surprising except there's no error. I've tried a few different things, such as prerolling before playing, but I've got idea why it's not working in this *specific* case. Can anyone give me some pointers?

I have all gst-plugins-* installed plus gst-libav. I'm using gstreamer 1.14.2 on ArchLinux.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a full debug log with `GST_DEBUG=6`. The actual error will be somewhere in there, the reason why something return `GST_FLOW_ERROR` (-5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone hitting similar problems: GIF decoding only works with a pull-based AppSrc. GIF seems to be the only popular web format (like jpgs, pngs, webms, mp4s, etc) which doesn't work with push-based AppSrc APIs.